# How to connect to a ldap through a proxy ldap?

Tags: perl, proxy, ldap

I've a little issue. At work, we will shortly use a proxy ldap to connect to our ldap.

However, my perl script used to connect directly to the ldap, and I can't find the right way to connect to the ldap through the ldap proxy.

The ldap team told me to simply change "my.local.ldap.org" by the url of the proxy.

But when I do that, I get nothing back except the error "Can't contact LDAP server at myscript.pl line X, < DATA> line 403."

I'm at my wits end, since I'm pretty new to perl.

How can I connect to my ldap throught the ldap proxy and get my data ?

There is my perl code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::LDAP;
use Net::SMTP;
use MIME::Lite;
use Getopt::Std;

connect_ldap();

sub connect_ldap {

    my @attributs = qw(uid subsidiary preferredLanguage);

    my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new(
        "my.local.ldap.org",
        port => 389
    ) or die open (STDERR, ">&SDTOUT");

    my $mesg = $ldap->bind (
        "cn=app_readonly,ou=account,ou=security,o=oubase",
        password => "mypassword"
    );

    $mesg = $ldap->search(
        base   => "o=oubase",
        scope => "sub",
        filter => "(&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(|(subsidiary=sub1)(subsidiary=sub2))(role=id=app_access,id=APP,*))",
        attrs => [ @attributs ]
    );

 printf "COUNT : %s\n", $mesg->count;
foreach my $entry ($mesg->entries) {
$entry->dump;
 }
print "==========================================\n";

        $mesg = $ldap->unbind;
        $ldap->unbind;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, there should not be any difference connecting through a proxy (provided that it is an *LDAP* proxy) compared to connecting to an LDAP server directly as long as the LDAP proxy is setup properly. Did you try telnetting to the host/port of the proxy to see if you got the correct connection information?

Comment: I did try a telnet on the port and the url and ip, and that works.
nmap tells me that the port is opened too.

So I'm more prone to think that's a ldap proxy setup that's block the connection.

Comment: You are probably right. You can always try a client like ldapsearch to test the LDAP proxy if you do not trust your code. Have the ldapsearch client bind as the user in your code.

Comment: did try that, (why didn't I think of that before). 

The client couldn't connect to the ldap. It's more and more probable that the ldap proxy is in for this.